# Changing context during AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-context

I have a service which runs for quite a while and collects data. At the end, it starts an `AsyncTask` and is finished. The catch is that in `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute()` I want to show a `Toast`, but I don't have a correct context, because by the time `AsyncTask` finishes, the service doesn't exist anymore. So how can I pass some other context to the service for this toast to show ?
   Even better would be showing the toast independently of where in the application the user is, because in worst-case scenario the `AsyncTask` may finish after quite a long time and user may have navigated elsewhere in the mean time. 
   In case this is not possible, what options do I have for informing user about `AsyncTask`'s success ?

Comment: have you tried getApplicationContext()?

Comment: Why do you run `AsyncTask` from `Service`? `Service` is the place for performing background operations, there is now needs to start any async tasks from it.

Comment: @Evos : is it possible to run AsyncTask from Service

Comment: There's valid reasons to run an AsyncTask from a service-  if your service needs to do two things at once.  Such as respond to calls from bound activities while still processing in the background.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I'm sory, but is this a question?Sure you can, but i'm not sure this is a right way to use service.

Comment: To @Gabe Sechan: sure you can, but you must stop your service only when all tasks are finihed.

Comment: @Evos Agreed.  I can't see a good reason for an AsyncTask to last beyond the lifetime of the service, it seems like something's wrong in the design, or that it should have been canceled when the service was stopped.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan you're absolutely right. It's all about design.

Comment: Good reason to run asyncTask from service is that when doing network operations in service without asyncTask, you get NetworkOnUIException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to discussion under the main question, the best solution in your case would be to  not stop your `Service` until all `AsyncTasks` (started from this service) will finish their work.